# Unable to resolve the url with location tag

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I have install let's encrypt with ngnix. Using the IP address , the url resolves i.e.

```
 http://<some-ip-address>:8000/subgraphs/name/foo/bar/graphql
```

I add a location tag to the ngnix config

```
     location /the_graph {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            rewrite ^/the_graph(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

which should resolve

```
https://<some_domain_name>/the_graph/subgraphs/name/foo/bar/graphql
```

However it resolves to a 404.

I would appreciate any assistance on this

Answer (score 0):

`try_files` is primarily for serving local files, but you want to use `proxy_pass`, so you need to remove it, otherwise it will generate a 404 response.

You are rewriting the URL to remove the prefix `/the_graph`.

You can either use [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) to do this:

```
location /the_graph/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
}
```

Notice the trailing `/` on both the `location` and `proxy_pass` values.

---

Or a `rewrite...break`:

```
location /the_graph {
    rewrite ^/the_graph(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

The capture (`$1`) already includes the leading `/` so you must not add another.

Comment: thanks , going with option 1, I can access the file directory afer the slash i.e. `https/foo/the_graph`, but not further down as it shows a 404 . i.e. `https/foo/the_graph/bar/graphql` . any idea what is going on?